# Error while getting length of command line arguments in java

Tags: java, string, command-line-arguments

I'm new to java.
here I try find the length first argument "arr[0]" passed of Command line argument. And how can i access each element of the arr[0].
Here is my program. Error is thrown at 5th line. C

```
class LengthArr
{
    public static void main(String[] arr)
    {
        int len= arr[0].length;  //Cannot find symble
        System.out.println(arr[0] + "Have length : " + len);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Error cannot find symble"*  Copy/paste these things, don't try to type them.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: @PawanMishra, your question is very unclear. Clarify whether you need length of command line arguments passed or length of first argument.

Comment: Given the fact there is a nice little comment war going on, I think you need to clarify what is you actually want.  Do you want to know the number of arguments passed to the program or the length of of those individual elements??

Comment: @PradeepSimha  +1, perhaps I also should have asked the OP to clarify before launching in with an answer.

Comment: It seems "clear" from the code (which won't work even if you got past line 5) that OP is expecting a palindrome in arr[0] - based on the line printed on success. However he accesses all arguments in turn with reckless abandon in the `for` loop. Can someone recommend a good intro text?

Comment: thanx to all for giving response.
@Pradeep Simha there i try to find the length of first argument passed threw command line..
And how can i access each element of first argument (arr[0])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code,

```
int l= arr[0].length;
```

in this line, arr[0] represents the value in array named as arr at 0th index.
Hence length function can be used in this way to find the length of value stored in array at 0th index.

```
int l = arr[0].length();
```

In order to find out the length of array, try this code:

```
int l = arr.length;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int l= arr[0].length;
```

Should be:

```
int l= arr[0].length();
```

My reading of the question is that you want the length of the actual argument supplied, since it is a palindrome tester.  Many people are guessing you mean the *number of arguments supplied.*  Thus, there is some confusion about what is required.

Comment: From OP, _how can i find the length of Command line args_ it gives only length of 0th element

Comment: @PradeepSimha From the title *"length of command line args in java"* - The question is ambiguous. You could argue both points.

Comment: he is trying to solve palindrome and thats why length of An Argument

Answer (score 4):

`arr[0]` is `String`. To get its length you need to use `arr[0].length()`.

`arr` is `String[]`. To get its length you need to use `arr.length`.

Comment: To add to this very concise explanation: The length of `arr` is the number of arguments supplied when the program is called.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] arr) {
    int numArgs, argLen, ii;
    numArgs = arr.length; // number of arguments
    System.out.println("There are " + numArgs + " arguments");
    for(ii=0; ii<numArgs; ii++)
    {
        argLen = arr[ii].length();
        System.out.println("The length of argument " + ii + " is " + argLen);
    }
}
```

I think this answers the question, regardless of what the question really was...

Comment: +1, nothing like 'covering all bases'.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] arr) {
    int len = arr.length;// to find length of array.
    System.out.println(len);
    int length = arr[0].length();// to find length of 0th element in arr.
}
```